# How to replace existentially quantified variable?

Tags: isabelle

Here is a simple type system:

```
datatype type =
  VoidType
| IntegerType
| RealType
| StringType

datatype val =
  VoidVal
| IntegerVal int
| RealVal real
| StringVal string

fun type_of :: "val ⇒ type" where
  "type_of (VoidVal) = VoidType"
| "type_of (IntegerVal _) = IntegerType"
| "type_of (RealVal _) = RealType"
| "type_of (StringVal _) = StringType"
```

with type conformance relation:

```
inductive less_type :: "type ⇒ type ⇒ bool" (infix "<" 65) where
  "IntegerType < RealType"
```

Integer values can be casted to corresponding real values:

```
inductive cast :: "val ⇒ val ⇒ bool" where
  "cast (IntegerVal x) (RealVal x)"
```

I'm trying to prove the following lemma. If type of a variable `x` conforms to `RealType`, then there exists a value `y` with type `RealType` and `x` can be casted to `y`.

```
lemma is_castable_to_real:
  "type_of x < RealType ⟹ ∃y. type_of y = RealType ∧ cast x y"
  apply (rule exI[of _ "RealVal v"])
```

I can prove the generic lemma using `cases` tactics:

```
lemma is_castable:
  "type_of x < τ ⟹ ∃y. type_of y = τ ∧ cast x y"
  by (cases x; cases τ; auto simp add: less_type.simps cast.simps)
```

But I'm trying to understand how to treat existential quantifiers in lemmas. So I'm trying to provide a concrete example `RealVal v` for `y`:

```
type_of x < RealType ⟹ ∃v. type_of (RealVal v) = RealType ∧ cast x (RealVal v)
```

The problem is that I get the following proposition instead:

```
 type_of x < RealType ⟹ type_of (RealVal v) = RealType ∧ cast x (RealVal v)
```

What is the kind of variable `v`? Is it universally quantified variable? How to make it existentially quantified one?

Comment: Are `P` and `Q` placeholders for other formulas?  If not, the lemma is not provable. If it is, it might help if you post the concrete formulas. In particular: Where does `y` come from? Does it appear in `P` or `Q`?

Comment: @peq I've added a more concrete example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prove an existential, you can give a concrete example. 
In your case, this example can be derived from the assumption of the lemma.

```
lemma is_castable_to_real:
assumes subtype_of_real: "type_of x < RealType"
shows "∃y. type_of y = RealType ∧ cast x y"
proof -
  have "type_of x = IntegerType"
    using subtype_of_real less_type.cases by blast

  from this obtain i where x_def: "x = IntegerVal i"
    by (cases x, auto)

  (* prove it for concrete example (RealVal i) *)
  have "type_of (RealVal i) = RealType ∧ cast x (RealVal i)"
    by (auto simp add: x_def cast.intros)

  (* From the concrete example, the existential statement follows: *)
  thus "∃y. type_of y = RealType ∧ cast x y" ..
qed
```

If you just use `v` before obtaining or defining it somehow, the value will be similar to `undefined`. It has the correct type, but you do not know anything about it.

If you start the `proof` without the dash (`-`) Isabelle will use the default tactic and you would get the subgoal `type_of ?y = RealType ∧ cast x ?y`. Here `?y` is a schematic variable and you can later provide any value that was already available before starting the proof. Maybe this is the kind of variable you get for `v`, but it is still not clear how you got to the last line in your question.